# excel - hyperlink to different workbook and specific worksheet? RunTime Error 5

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks Workbook1 and Workbook2. In my  Workbook2 in one of the worksheet Column A contains cell reference and Column E contains sheet name of Workbook1.

I basically want to create hyperlink on the used range of Column B of the Workbook2 so that when I click on any of the cells of column B it should take me to the Workbook1

Currently I am getting error "Run Time Error 5 on the below mentioned line:

```
 sh.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cell, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & "C:\Users\ Workbook1.xlsx" & "'" & Cells("E:E").Value & "'!" & Cell.Address
```

Overall code:

```
sub hyerlinkworkb ()

Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary Sheet")
Set sw = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsx")
       lr = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = sh.Range("B2:B" & lr)
    For Each Cell In Rng
      sh.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cell, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & "C:\Users\workbook1.xlsx" & "'" & Cells("E:E").Value & "'!" & Cell.Address

 Next
end sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I believe are wrong with this.

Firstly the syntax its disliking is the `cells("E:E").value` I think you need to specify one cell value at a time.

Secondly the workbook address should be under address and then the sheet and cell reference under sub address.

Try something along these lines. I've tested it an it appears to work with some dummy date

```
Sub hyerlinkworkb()

Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary Sheet")
Set sw = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsx")
       lr = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = sh.Range("B2:B" & lr)
i = 1
    For Each cell In Rng
    sh.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell, Address:="C:\Users\workbook1.xlsx", SubAddress:="'" & Range("E" & i).Value & "'!" & cell.value
    i = i + 1
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried the above code its taking me to the sheet name mentioned in Column E however in Column B cell references are also given so its not taking me there

Comment: Eg if  B2 value = $G$7 and E2 value has sheet name as "abc" so currently it is creating a hyperlink on B2 and taking me to abc sheet however I want that it should take me to G7 of sheet abc

Comment: Change the very end to cell.Value rather than cell.Address and see if that gives you the desired result